# Disable fastlane summary output

Tags: fastlane

I'm using fastlane and I find that the default output of the command is quite verbose.
This is the default output for one of my lanes, 46 lines of text.
https://pastebin.com/f30V071X

I found a way to reduce this output setting 3 special env variables

```
ENV["SNAPSHOT_SKIP_OPEN_SUMMARY"] = "1"
ENV["FASTLANE_SKIP_UPDATE_CHECK"] = "1"
ENV["FASTLANE_HIDE_TIMESTAMP"] = "1"
```

This is the minimum output I can have: https://pastebin.com/uUBvbj6V

Is there any way to disable everything accessory and only keep the output coming from the lane itself?